# Vectorian Giotto import flash.external.ExternalInterface syntax error?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

I'm creating a scaleform HUD for UDK, and everything is created. The problem is that i want the healthbar and weapons bar to rotate slightly to give a 3d effect. When I try to do this i get 2 errors:

on line 1, Characters 1-2, Syntax Error: i

on line 6, CHaracters 1-10, Syntax error: intrinsic

```
import flash.external.ExternalInterface
import gfx.motion.Tween
_global.gfxExtension = true;

function init()
{
    _root.HealthBar._yrotation = 30;
    _root.Weapons._yrotation = 30;
}

init();
```

Is it because this is for actionscript 3.0? how would i convert it to 2.0? Thank You

Comment: If you are trying to run ActionScript 3 code in an AS2 environment, it will totally not work. I wouldn't know how to convert it to AS2, but I think I saw a 1997 Edition of Flash Coders Monthly (Special Windows XP edition!) with an article on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this thread, which talks about some challenges with using ExternalInterface: http://forums.epicgames.com/threads/802762-Developing-Scaleform-UI-with-Vectorian-Giotto